# Start activity from service onPause called immediately

Tags: android

I have created on Activity for Alarm options. When alarm triggered in alarm manager I started this Activity. But the problem is the alarm RING is playing only on **screen on** state, If **screen is locked** then process going like this. `onCreate() --> Screen unlocked --> onPause()` called immediately, so player is stoped.

```
public class MediaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_alarm);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmSound == null) {
            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            if (alarmSound == null) {
                alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            }
        }

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), alarmSound);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        try {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                finish();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }
    }
}
```

How should I overcome this issue?